# How to get methods from an API?

Tags: javascript, python, api

I'm trying to call a method from the musixMatch API. I am trying to do this in either Javascript or Python. There is not much listed about this listed on the documentation. Is there some way to import it? Do I need to make an AJAX request?

https://developer.musixmatch.com/documentation/api-methods

Comment: What do you mean *"import it"*? If you mean are there client libraries, see https://pypi.org/search/?q=musixmatch or https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=musixmatch. But *something* needs to make an HTTP request to the API; you could write it yourself using a lower level request library if you wanted.

Comment: I’m not really sure what to do. I don’t think there are client libraries. If I just make a urllib.request to it, will i be able to use the methods from the website?

Comment: 1. Both of those searches have results, so that seems like an odd conclusion. 2. That's one way to make an HTTP request from Python, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an official MusixMatch SDK, supporting both Python and Javascript: https://github.com/musixmatch/musixmatch-sdk

The SDK can help your communication with the API without exposing some abstractions like Ajax.

As for your last question, yes, you have to make a HTTP request in *some way* in order to talk to the API. If you're using Javascript on the browser, you'll need AJAX, but for Python you'll use a plain `request` object. However, if you use the SDK, your code will not need to implement this, as I said.

Take a look at this example (in Python):

```py
import swagger_client #imports the API
swagger_client.configuration.api_key['apikey'] = '_YOUR_API_KEY_' #starts the API with your key
album_api_instance = swagger_client.AlbumApi() #Calls the Album API
```

Now you can use the `album_api_instance` object to call the API (in case you want an Album):

```py
album_id = '14250417'
response_format = 'json' #json, jsonp or xml
response = api_instance.album_get_get(album_id, format=response_format)
print(response)
```

As you can see, this lets you call the API without worrying about HTTP or requests.

If you want to call an endpoint other than the Album API (Tracks, Artists, etc.), you can [download the SDK as a zip](https://github.com/musixmatch/musixmatch-sdk/blob/master/dist/python-client-generated.zip) and browse into `python-client/swagger_client/apis/`. There you will find .py files exposing the endpoints, well documented.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python requests library to consume the API as the following

```
import requests
url = 'https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/'
requests.get(url)
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: So after I make a request to it I can just use the methods whenever I want to?

Comment: You need the read the documentation to adapt your URL according to the data you want to retrieve, for example: https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/chart.artists.get?page=1&page_size=3&country=it

Comment: Thanks I just need to put in the API key in the parameter as well.